# How to disallow access to an url called without parameters with robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, web-crawler

I would like to deny web robots to access a url like this:

http://www.example.com/export

allowing this kind of url instead:

http://www.example.com/export?foo=value1

A spider bot is calling `/export` without query string causing a lot of errors on my log.
Is there a way to manage this filter on robots.txt?

Comment: Even if it were possible (Which I'm not sure about, seeing as  technically, both addresses are one and the same resource), I wouldn't trust bots to understand it properly.

Comment: @Pekka I see, I think I have to handle it programmatically in a better way. At the moment, this thing is writing a lot of noise on my log.

Comment: I see. I wrote out what I would do - not sure whether it helps you with your logs though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have problems with bots hitting the first URL in your example.

As said in the comment, this is probably not possible, because `http://www.example.com/export` is the resource's base URL. Even if it were possible as per the standard, I wouldn't trust bots to understand this properly.

I would also not send a `401 Access denied` or similar header if the URL is called without a query string for the same reason: A bot could think that the resource is out of bounds entirely.

What I would do in your situation is, if somebody arrives at

```
 http://www.example.com/export
```

send a `301 Moved permanently` redirect to the same URL and a query string with some default values, like

```
 http://www.example.com/export?foo=0
```

this should keep the search engine index clean. (It won't fix the logging problem you state in your comment, though.)